# add column in ORACLE with DEFAULT value and NULLABLE column type

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

We recently had our deployments crash because of a very strange reason.

```
alter table eugen add eugencolumn number default 99;
```

Is not mentioning the column as 'NOT NULL' making such a big difference? I want to understand why this query is creating problems, adding a 'NOT NULL' constraint solves it but is there any other work around? if you do not want the column to not be null?

Thanks,
Much Appreciated.

Comment: how did your deployment scripts "crash"? Were there any errors? We don't know how your deployment scripts are structured, since you haven't provided that information, so it's going to be very hard to diagnose the issue - especially since my crystal ball is on the blink! *{;-) A simple test script that demonstrates the issue would go a long way for us to be able to a) recreate the issue and b) help you.

Comment: forgetting the deployment crash for now.. whats the difference between     alter table eugen add eugencolumn number default 99; and     alter table eugen add eugencolumn number default 99 not null;

Comment: One creates the column as nullable with a default value, the other as not nullable with a default value. It's perfectly valid to add a default column to a nullable field - see: https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_EZ65U038HYO5ZD0WSM8FB6NGQ.html

Comment: actually many people have documented performance issues when a not null value is not added in the end.. I am trying to understand why.. :) Thanks a lot for your reply :)

Comment: You're probably talking about something that [Tom Kyte has already answered and explained](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:100515465349335::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:2575782100346318728).

Answer (score 0):

Actually your Question is not clear .If you want to set 99 as default value after modifying table structure execute the query.
*update eugen set eugencolumn = 99;*